# Active menu not highlighted in Boostrap and Javascript, how do I solve this?

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried to highlight the active menu bar via the code below but can not figure out why it is not working. Would someone kindly lead me through. Thank you.

Both my HTML and my Js scripts are below:

```js
$(".nav a").on("click", function(){
   $(".nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
   $(this).parent().addClass("active");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">

<!-- Collapsed Hamburger -->
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#app-navbar-collapse">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
</div>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li class="active"><a href="home">Dashboard</a></li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Transactions
<span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="#">Payments</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Make Receipts</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Payments on Date</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Valuable Customer</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">SMS
<span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="#">Bulk SMS</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Most Valuable SMS</a></li>
<li><a href="#">SMS</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
<!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
&nbsp;
</ul>

</div>
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: at this code snippet.. it have highllighted.. did you mean you don't have it if on your browser?

Comment: Hi @AKZhang for the first one "Dashboard" it is okay. However when I click on the next say sms it is not highlighted, how do I solve this?

Comment: the bootstrap.min.js was not getting loaded as it was a http call blocked over https. Now your menu items are expanding properly. is this was your issue ?

Comment: Hi @BobMwenda refer below for my answer

Comment: Hi @AKZhang I have commented on your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(".nav a").on("click", function(){
   $(".nav li").removeClass("active");
   $(this).parent().addClass("active");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">

<!-- Collapsed Hamburger -->
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#app-navbar-collapse">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
</div>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li class="active"><a href="home">Dashboard</a></li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Transactions
<span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="#">Payments</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Make Receipts</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Payments on Date</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Valuable Customer</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">SMS
<span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="#">Bulk SMS</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Most Valuable SMS</a></li>
<li><a href="#">SMS</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
<!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
&nbsp;
</ul>

</div>
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hi there, Well my issue is when I click on say SMS menu item. It should be highlighted as the active tab. I am struggling to achieve that.

Comment: Hi, you want SMS tab to be highlighted right, if i understand it correct? Please refer my answer, Do you want the first item to be highlighted inside sms?

Comment: isn't the code snippet already working? while you click on SMS tab, it will dropdown submenu and highlighted.. as for highlighting the sub menu.. you need to put condition again to achieve that if got clicked

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove your add and then add CSS to force making active for sub menu and so on

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>
ul li ul li .active {background: lightskyblue; }
</style>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">

<!-- Collapsed Hamburger -->
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#app-navbar-collapse">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
</div>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li class="active"><a href="home">Dashboard</a></li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Transactions
<span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="#" class="active" >Payments</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Make Receipts</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Payments on Date</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Valuable Customer</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">SMS
<span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="#">Bulk SMS</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Most Valuable SMS</a></li>
<li><a href="#">SMS</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
<!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
&nbsp;
</ul>

</div>
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hi there, Well my issue is when I click on say SMS menu item. It should be highlighted as the active tab. I am struggling to achieve that.